# Check that a Word.Document is a mailmerge and remove mailmerge if so

Tags: c#, vb.net, ms-word, office-automation

We are experiencing a strange issue when opening a Word document that has been configured as a "mail merge".

When you open the document manually, i.e. by simply double-clicking on it on your computer, it shows a message box:

"**Opening this document will run the following SQL command:**

**SELECT * FROM** (some filename here)

**Data from your database will be placed in the document. Do you want to continue?**"

When you click "no" you can then go to the Mailings ribbon, "Start Mail Merge" and choose "Normal Word Document". If you then save the document all this mail merge stuff disappears and you no longer get the message when you open the document.

Now for our application. We simply open the Document from a Word.Documents object:

```
oWDoc = oWDocs.Open(FileName:=sFile)
```

Now ...

I recorded a Macro to see what was happening when we perform those actions, and all it records is:

```
oWDoc.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = -1
```

But when I step through my code, after it opens the document as per the first code snippet, when I check the MainDocumentType before it executes that statement it is already -1 (wdNotAMergeDocument), and if I then follow that by

```
oWDoc.Save()
```

... it makes no difference. If I subsequently then try to open the document manually by double-clicking on it I still get that message and I still need to go through the motions to remove it.

I recorded another Macro to see whether there is anything different in how the document is opened but the Documents.Open call appears to pass all the defaults so it should, I would have thought, be identical to how we're opening it programmatically.

**My questions**

How can I:

1. Check this programmatically and
2. Remove it programmatically so that it really does disappear even if the user subsequently opens the document manually?

Our code is in VB but answers in C# are welcome

Comment: Before you save the document you might need to do this,  ActiveDocument.MailMerge.MainDocumentType = wdNotAMergeDocument  .
Have you tried .SaveAs2.

Comment: If the suggestion by @dbasnett isn't enough, perhaps try oWDoc.Saved = False (to try to "dirty" the document so that when you invoke the Save method, Word actually does something). Because there are other situations where Word's object model doesn't notice that you changed something. Untested.

Comment: In VBA, you'd use wdApp.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone when opening the document, where wdApp is the Word Application. See **Run a Mailmerge from Excel, Sending the Output to Individual Files** at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

Comment: Hello folks, thanks for the suggestions; sorry I got side tracked into something completely unrelated but I'm hoping to give these a go today.

Comment: @macropod - Yes, when I set .DisplayAlerts to -2 I see the message popping up so the user would know something's not right.

Comment: @jonsson yes, when I set the .Saved property to False and then I .Save the document, it works but ....

Comment: ... as per @dbasnett 's suggestion I can set the MainDocumentType to wdNotAMergeDocument. My problem is that by the time I open it, Word has already done this itself. This means that currently the best I can do is ALWAYS set the property to wdNotAMergeDocument, ALWAYS set .Saved to False and ALWAYS then Save the document. There doesn't, however, appear to be a .DisplayAlerts property that would allow me to NOT show a message to the user, but somehow catch it programmatically, so that I could then set the MainDocumentType and .Save ONLY when it's necessary to do so? Any ideas?

Comment: Okay.... the good news is that this issue only arises for Word documents we use as "templates" for documents our application generates, so we can restrict this to the point where such templates MUST be "docx" documents. That will allow me me query the internal XML and check for a mailMergeSource in settings.xml._rels, and linkToQuery, connectString or query nodes in settings.xml. If we see those we show the user a warning and instructions on how to remove the mail merge manually. After that, they're on their own.

Comment: You should use an ordinary document or a mailmerge main document for the mailmerge, not a Word template. If you then set wdApp.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone before opening the document, that will cause Word to treat it as a normal document instead of as a mailmerge main document. You can then run your query code. If you subsequently close the document without saving, it will remain whatever document type it was before it was opened. That approach gives the flexibility of allowing the document be used as a mailmerge main document for mailmerges without using code should the need arise.

Comment: That's what we do. Our "templates" are .docx documents. And then we generate new word documents from them. When the user opens those generated documents from our application we use word automation to open the docs. wdAlertsNone is the default so no errors are shown. All good, you'd think, but no. We got complaints "YoUr GeNeRaTeD dOcS tAkE 30 SeCoNdS tO cLoSe, yOuR sOfTwArE iS cRaP"... took us ages to discover they had imported MailMerge documents....